# How does the equivalence operator work with arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

Code:

```
$arr = array( 10, 20, 30 );
$arr1 = array(
       1=>30,
       2=>20,
       0=>10
);
var_dump( $arr == $arr1 );

$a = array( 1, 2, 3);
$b = array(
       1=>2,
       2=>3,
       0=>1
 );
var_dump($a == $b);
```

This outputs:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: That looks like the equality operator, rather than the equivalence operator...

Comment: == is equivalence (more commonly known as "equality"). === is "identity" (as in "identical")

Comment: @Rowland: equality operator in PHP is ===

Comment: i think == this operator behaves for comparing value only 
and === this operator works for comparing values as well as order 
right ?

Comment: so the output should have both bool(true) bool(true)

Comment: hey thanks it is very useful as got the difference between order and keys of an array

Comment: [3,2,1] is not equal nor equivalent to [1,2,3].

Answer (score 6):

Two arrays will be considered equal if their corresponding values are the same.

In your first example you are comparing two arrays:

```
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 30, 20]
```

Obviously these are not the same, so it returns false. The second example though:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

...are the same. Am I missing something here?

---

If you want to test if two arrays have the same members, see this question:
[Algorithm to tell if two arrays have identical members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245509)

If you just want to see they have the same totals, you can use [array_sum](http://www.php.net/array_sum)

Comment: this is a equivalence operator it should consider only values and not the index , if it is an identity operator(===) then it should consider  order as well

Comment: @jackie: in array values do not exist w/o index.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify keys for `array`, php automatically selects numbers, starting with 0.
Therefore, the following pairs of lines mean the same:

```
$arr = array(10,20,30);
$arr = array(0=>10,1=>20,2=>30);

$a = array(1,2,3);
$a = array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>3);
```

Comment: this is a equivalence operator it should consider only values and not the index , if it is an identity operator(===) then it should consider  order as well

Answer (score 0):

It's to be expected, that

```
array(10,20,30) != array(10,30,20)
```

and

```
array(1,2,3) == array(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very broad question, but in the case of an array, it compares on an index-by-index basis.

In your first block of code, $arr is not equal to $arr1 because 30 != 10 and 10!=30.

In the second block of code, you are specifying that at index 0, the value is 1. At index 1, the value is 2, and at index 2, the value is 3. Thus, you have the same array.

Comment: this is a equivalence operator it should consider only values and not the index , if it is an identity operator(===) then it should consider  order as well

Comment: Well, in PHP you cannot have an array value without an index. Are you saying that (1,2,3) and (3,2,1) are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Given some of your comments, I think it would be useful if you read up on [array type in php](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Mainly the fact that there is no key-less arrays.
And don't forget [comparison operators](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) as well.

Comment: hey thanks
it is very useful as got the difference between order and keys of an array

Answer (score 0):

th equality operator is `===` in php and within an array `=>` is correct. also `$arr !=$arr1` coz `20 !=30`, `30!=20` as per you have assigned.